# Xamarin.iOS audio streaming not working, events not being triggered

Tags: ios, events, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So, my problem is that I'm trying to stream audio on Xamarin.iOS with the AudioFileStream and OutputAudioQueue classes. I have added handlers for the PacketDecoded and PropertyFound events, but they are not being triggered. What's wrong? My code is below...

```
class AudioStreamer : IAudioStreamer // this is my dependency service interface
{
    bool outputStarted;

    AudioFileStream afs;
    OutputAudioQueue oaq;

    public void StartStreaming(string url)
    {
        afs = new AudioFileStream(AudioFileType.MP3);

        // event handlers, these are never triggered
        afs.PacketDecoded += OnPacketDecoded;
        afs.PropertyFound += OnPropertyFound;

        GetAudio(url);
    }

    void GetAudio(string url)
    {
        // HTTP
        NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(
            NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration, 
            new SessionDelegate(afs), 
            NSOperationQueue.MainQueue);

        var dataTask = session.CreateDataTask(new NSUrl(url));
        dataTask.Resume();
    }

    // event handler - never executed
    void OnPropertyFound(object sender, PropertyFoundEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Property == AudioFileStreamProperty.ReadyToProducePackets)
        {
            oaq = new OutputAudioQueue(afs.StreamBasicDescription);
            oaq.BufferCompleted += OnBufferCompleted;
        }
    }

    // another event handler never executed
    void OnPacketDecoded(object sender, PacketReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr outBuffer;
        oaq.AllocateBuffer(e.Bytes, out outBuffer);
        AudioQueue.FillAudioData(outBuffer, 0, e.InputData, 0, e.Bytes);
        oaq.EnqueueBuffer(outBuffer, e.Bytes, e.PacketDescriptions);

        // start playing if not already
        if(!outputStarted)
        {
            var status = oaq.Start();
            if (status != AudioQueueStatus.Ok)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not start audio queue");
            outputStarted = true;
        }
    }

    void OnBufferCompleted(object sender, BufferCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        oaq.FreeBuffer(e.IntPtrBuffer);
    }
}

// instantiated in GetAudio()
class SessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDataDelegate
{
    readonly AudioFileStream afs;

    public SessionDelegate(AudioFileStream afs)
    {
        this.afs = afs;
    }

    // this is, too, never executed
    public override void DidReceiveData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSData data)
    {
        afs.ParseBytes((int)data.Length, data.Bytes, false);
    }
}
```

Btw, I mostly copied the code from [this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q47oK2KpC84).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct...

1) I see the "http://" comment in your source.  Are your streaming from a `http://` source without adding an ATS exception? If so, the `dataTask.Resume();` is a "silent code failure" and thus none of your delegates/events will be called, **BUT** iOS will log it.

Check output log for something like:

```
StreamingAudio[13602:591658] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

Use `https://` sources, but if you have to turn ATS off completely for testing:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

Note: Search `iOS ATS` for more info or details in order to only allow non-secure `http://` from the server(s) that you would be streaming from, but the iOS' future is `https://` only so start preparing... ;-)

2) If the URL source provided to NSUrlSession produces a  **Connection refused**, that is a silent failure, AND there is no logging about it and of course none of your delegates/events are called... Pre-test that your streaming web services are active, try using `curl`, `wget`, etc.. to test the stream...

3) I see your streaming MP3s, so you *should* be OK, but remember there are hundreds of variations to the format and iOS does not stream/play them all so try a different mp3 encoded via a different toolset just to double-check...